# Google Tag Manager + Magento EE 1.13.1 + Custom HTML Tag

Tags: magento, google-tag-manager, magento-1.13, commission-junction, affiliates

Should be simple!  I'm just trying to insert the orderId and transactiontotal dataLayer variables into my commission junction tracking tag, but can't seem to get it to populate the variables in GTM debug mode.  DataLayer variables are working, so I know that's not the issue.

Any suggestions on why this isn't showing up?

Comment: It's currently: <!-- begin Commission Junction Pixel -->
   <img src="https://www.emjcd.com/u?CID=XXXXXXX&OID={{orderId}}&TYPE=XXXXXX&AMOUNT={{transactionTotal}}&CURRENCY=''&METHOD=IMG" height="1" width="20">
    <!-- end Commission Junction Pixel -->

Comment: @Jason update your question to include the code you posted above.